# Why does this raycast code give me a NullReferenceException?

Tags: unity, c#, android, raycasting

The Error in the code is NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object for if (hitxx.collider.tag == "soldier")
Please help! Thanks in advance

```
 void Update () {       
            Physics.Raycast (eyeenemy.transform.position, (eyeenemyfront.transform.position - eyeenemy.transform.position) * 20,out hitxx);

            Debug.DrawRay (eyeenemy.transform.position, (eyeenemyfront.transform.position - eyeenemy.transform.position) * 20,Color.green);
            if (hitxx.collider.tag == "soldier") {
                gameObject.transform.LookAt (soldier.transform.position);
                Debug.Log ("chuchu");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `hitxx`, of type `RaycastHit`, is only initialized by `Physics.Raycast()` if it actually hits something. Otherwise it will remain unchanged since the last hit or will be null if nothing has been hit in the past. You are failing to handle the condition in which nothing is hit. When you get to checking the tag, it is trying to access a collider on a null reference.

`Physics.Raycast()` actually returns a bool representing whether something was hit. You could use that in a condition so be sure that `hitxx` is not null.

```
bool isHit = Physics.Raycast (eyeenemy.transform.position,
        (eyeenemyfront.transform.position - eyeenemy.transform.position) * 20,out hitxx);
...
//will not attempt to access hitxx if isHit is false
if (isHit && hitxx.collider.tag == "soldier") {
    ...
}
```